# Auto re-fill form fields after server side validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I searched a lot and cannot find how to make the form fields re-fill after the form has been validated on the server side and returned false.

E.g. In my registration form I have all fields filled in but the username is already taken. Server then returns a message that this username is taken and together with that all fields go empty again and user has to start filling in the form from scratch.

Is it even possible without jQuery? I remember having it working some time in the past but cannot recollect how I did that.

[edit to add my code:]

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method='POST' name="register_form" onsubmit="return isEmpty()"> 
Name:
<input type='text' class='req' id='name' name='name' ></div>
Username:
<input type='text' class='req' id='username' name='username'></div>
E-mail:
<input type='text' class='req' id='email' name='email'></div>
Repeat e-mail:
<input type='text' class='req' id='repeatemail' name='repeatemail'></div>
Password:
<input type='password' class='req' id='password' name='password'></div>
Repeat password:
<input type='password' class='req' id='repeatpassword' name='repeatpassword'></div>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
```

Comment: yes possible by using session variables

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. You can do it by using session variables.

in your form page echo  session variable for each input fields:

```
<?php
session_start(); 


<input type="text" name="i1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['i1']; ?>" /> // create input field like this with different names
```

in your form submitting php set all session variables for each input :

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['i1'] = $_REQUEST['i1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yrs. of course. Server side code can refill *any* data in the HTML it generates.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Yes ,they are right
    Get all the data in Session- use it as code start here;
      session_start();
        $_SESSION['form-data']=$_POST;

       here all the post data in the array form send to the session in same array form 
      and you can get and used it in value field in your form 

 <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['form-data'])){echo     $_SESSION['form-data']['username']; }?>" />
```